# ColdFusion - pass XML as parameter to xmlTransform() in CF10

Tags: xml, xslt, parameters, coldfusion

Good day -

In ColdFusion 9, we could pass XML parameters to xmlTransform(), like this:

```
<cfxml variable="parm">
  <users>
     <user>Joe Blow</user>
     <user>Jane Doe</user>
  </users>
</cfxml>

<cfset params=structNew()>
<cfset params["users"]=parm>
<cfset newXML=xmlTransform(xmlFile,xslFile,params)>
```

In the XSL then, we could accept the "users" argument:

```
<xsl:param name="users" select="." />
```

And use it as a variable, run XPath on it, etc.

However, with ColdFusion 10, passing an XML argument to any XSL results in an error.  It is quite unhelpful, and none of the error logs show any detail.

The error shown is simply:

```
    An error occured while Transforming an XML document.
```

and

> coldfusion.xml.XmlProcessException: An error occured while Transforming an XML document. at coldfusion.xml.XmlProcessor.doTransform(XmlProcessor.java:508) at coldfusion.xml.XmlProcessor.access$100(XmlProcessor.java:82) at coldfusion.xml.XmlProcessor$3.run(XmlProcessor.java:455) at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method) at coldfusion.xml.XmlProcessor.transform(XmlProcessor.java:451) at coldfusion.xml.XmlProcessor.transform(XmlProcessor.java:440) at coldfusion.runtime.CFPage.XmlTransform(CFPage.java:359) at cftestxml2ecfm41929416.runPage(E:\test\testxml.cfm:36) at coldfusion.runtime.CfJspPage.invoke(CfJspPage.java:244) at coldfusion.tagext.lang.IncludeTag.doStartTag(IncludeTag.java:444) at coldfusion.filter.CfincludeFilter.invoke(CfincludeFilter.java:65) at coldfusion.filter.IpFilter.invoke(IpFilter.java:64) at coldfusion.filter.ApplicationFilter.invoke(ApplicationFilter.java:443) at ) ... (etc)

I've narrowed it down to specifically the action of passing XML as an argument.  If it's changed to a string instead of XML, it "works" in the sense that it doesn't get this error.  That's fine for an empty XSLT, but of course we need it to be passed as XML so that we can e.g. use XPath on the data.

Has ColdFusion 10 changed so that it no longer allows XML parameters to xmlTransform()?  Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: According to the [documentation found here](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ColdFusion/10.0/CFMLRef/WSc3ff6d0ea77859461172e0811cbec22c24-6e8e.html) the `XmlTransform()` function still accepts the same parameters. There is a note that ColdFusion 10 _Added support for XSLT 2.0 syntax_. Can you show us an example of the failing XML that you are trying to pass to the function?

Comment: Hi Miguel, the error in CF10 is independent of the XML that is passed.   Passing the "users" XML, shown above, as a parameter is enough to cause the issue. Commenting out the params, or making "users" a string, eliminates the error.  There is no need to try to access the passed XML within the XSL; simply passing *any* XML causes an error.

Comment: Can you show the XSLT you are using?

Comment: Hello, I didn't note this explicitly, but it didn't matter.  The XSL could be blank but for the XML declaration, and it failed.  The act of passing an XML argument to XMLTransform() is what caused the error, independent of the XSL.  Note that the question is almost two years old and I've not retested since.

Answer (score 1):

I saw the same thing and this still fails - but noticed it failed because the "value" of the parameter struct happened to be a number.

For example, `<cfset xslparameters["regionID"] = 223>` fails, as does `<cfset xslparameters["regionID"] = "223">`

The trick is to force wrap as a string: `<cfset xslparameters["regionID"] = ToString("223")>`

or in my case technically,

`<cfset xslparameters["regionID"] = "#ToString(serviceRegion.region_id)#">`

Answer (score 0):

**Another important safety tip:**

If you're running CF on Linux, keep in mind that CF changes all struct keys to uppercase.

**For example:**

In the XSL, the `<xsl:param name="PARMNAME">` element and the `$PARMNAME` references in the body need to have all parameter names converted to uppercase.